# Magento 2: What's relationship of getQuote() with getItemsCount()?

Tags: magento2

Magento version: 2.0.0

In ther Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart, there has a function is:

```
/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 * @return int
 */
public function getItemsCount()
{
    return $this->getQuote()->getItemsCount();
}
```

`getQuote()` is from the Class `AbstractCart` because `Cart` is extends `\Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\AbstractCart`.

According the Eclipse helping, `getItemsCount()` should be from `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote`.

In `\Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\AbstractCart`, the Class `Quote` is just only invoked with `use` keywords but not initialize or extend.

So, I am confused the relationship of `getQuote()` with `getItemsCount()`. 
`getQuote()` is not extend from `Quote` class, why it can use the `getItemsCount()` of `Quote`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code from vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Cart/AbstractCart.php:

```
public function getQuote()
{
    if (null === $this->_quote) {
        $this->_quote = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote();
    }
    return $this->_quote;
}
```

`$this->_$quote` is an object of Magento/Quote/Model/Quote class. Thus, the relationship is quite certain.